# EF Core Spatial Data not working after SQL Server upgrade

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

**The previous database was SQL Server 2008 on a Windows Web Server 2008. 
The current one is SQL Server 2017 on a Windows Server 2012. Is the issue related to the OS?**

I was using EF Core with NetTopologySuite over SQL Server 2008 and it was working just fine.

I moved the database to a SQL Server 2017 instance but when querying I get this error :

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":  System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.

The code is the same, no changes. However I have a feeling something is missing on SQL Server 2017 or somewhere between.

```
private async Task<List<PotentialProjectViewModel>> GetPotentialLocations(Project p)
    {
        return await _db.PotentialProjects
            .Where(x => x.Location != null)
            .Where(x => x.Location.Distance(p.Locatie) < 950)
            .Select(x => new PotentialProjectViewModel
            {
                LocatieLatitudine = x.AddressLatitude,
                LocatieLongitudine = x.AddressLongitude,
                NumeProiect = x.ProjectName
            })
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

The database context is configured as it follows :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(ConnectionString,
                    sqlOptions => sqlOptions.UseNetTopologySuite());
        }
    }
```

I have installed NetTopologySuite nuget package and also Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite.

Comment: Is it possible Spatial Data was removed from EF Core?

Comment: No, spatial data was not removed

Comment: can you paste a bigger complete code snippet?

Comment: Added code snippets

Comment: @GeorgeM. did you ever figure this out?  running into the same issue